# Access with SQL table accessable from SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-access, sharepoint-2007

I've worked with Access since the first version, until version 2007, where I mostlky worked with SQL.Net.  Now I have created an Access db linked to SQL tables.  I need to allow my users to get to the database via SharePoint.  I have tried openning the Access db, Move to Share Point, paste the sharepoint url site I want to put the db. After I click next I get an error "Microsoft Office Access cannot perform the export operation"..  This doe not tell me much!  Why can't it be performed?? Could someone please help me make this db accessable from SharePoint.

Thnak you.

Comment: Do you want to distribute your Access front end with Sharepoint, or do you want the existing SQL Server to be available to the Access front end via the Sharepoint server? I'm not sure the latter is doable, nor why you'd want to do it in the first place. Sharepoint is built on top of SQL Server, but hides a lot of SQL Server's functionality from you, so you'd be giving up a huge amount of control/accessibility.

Comment: Just noticed the comment on my questions, thanks.  We just need the users to be able to enter/edit data, so Access front end with SharePoint should be fine.  I beleive the backend tables would remain SQL which is how we built the Access database.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the role that Sharepoint would play here. If the back end is SQL Server, you don't need Sharepoint, unless you're using Sharepoint to distribute the front end. Otherwise, it just isn't relevant.